# How can I make my plugin copy a line into the clipboard?

Tags: sublimetext3

This Sublime Text plugin randomly selects a position in a text file and places the cursor there as if the user had clicked on that position using the mouse.

I also want it to copy the line of that random position into the clipboard. Is it possible to do that in the same program?

```py
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import random

class JumpToRandomPositionCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    """
    When invoked, randomly select a character in the current
    file and jump the cursor to that position. Does nothing
    if the current file is empty or if the current view does
    not represent a file.
    """
    def run(self, edit):
        view = self.view

        if view.size() > 0 and view.settings().get("is_widget", False) == False:
            view.sel().clear()

            pos = random.randrange(0, view.size())
            view.sel().add(sublime.Region(pos, pos))

            view.show(pos)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways that do what you want to do here. So, here are some snippets of code you can add to the plugin you provided in your question. In each case, these bits of code would go into the plugin inside of your final `if` statement as the last line (i.e. after the call to `view.show()`. The position is important; is has to only happen if the position was changed, and (in the case of the first snippet) it has to happen after the cursor has moved to the new location.

First, the easiest one. Sublime contains the following setting in the default preferences:

```json
    // If true, the copy and cut commands will operate on the current line
    // when the selection is empty, rather than doing nothing.
    "copy_with_empty_selection": true,
```

When this is turned on (which as seen here it is by default), if you try to trigger the `copy` or `cut` commands when there's no selection, each command will assume you meant to work on the whole line.

If you're working in this way, the following line added to your plugin is enough to do the job:

```py
view.run_command('copy')
```

That is, ask the view to run the `copy` command, which is what would happen if you manually pressed the key binding. The plugin sets a single cursor into the line in a random position with an empty selection, so this would operate on that empty selection and copy the line.

If on the other hand you don't use this setting, or you want the command to work regardless of what it is set to, then you need to do a bit more work. That would look something like this:

```py
line = view.full_line(pos)
text = view.substr(line)
sublime.set_clipboard(text)
```

Here we ask Sublime to tell us what span of text represents the line that the random position is sitting inside of. We then extract that text from the buffer and add it to the clipboard.